# foreach loop duplicating first row

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

This is the code that I have

```
<?php
$checkbox = $_REQUEST['checkbox']; 
for($i=0; $i<count($_REQUEST['checkbox']); $i++){ 
    $del_id = $checkbox[$i]; 
    $get_info=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `pending_payments` WHERE `id` = ?");
    $get_info->bind_param('i', $del_id);
    $get_info->execute();
    $result = $get_info->get_result();
    $info[] = $result->fetch_assoc();
    foreach($info as $row){ 
        $amount = $row['amount'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        echo"
        <input type='text' style='height: 35px;' name='Amount[]' value='".$amount."' />
        <input type='text' style='height: 35px;' name='EmailAddress[]' value='".$email."' /><br />
        ";
    }
}
?>
```

The problem that I am having is that it is duplicating the first row it finds. I have 2 entries into the database, and it is repeating the first row twice before going on the the third, when I `print_r` `$info` it gives me this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [username] => ccarson030308 [amount] => 5.00 [processor] => PayPal [email] => ccarson030308@gmail.com [submitted_date] => 1372030166 ) )
```

then shows the `echo` for that line then starts over and shows

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [username] => ccarson030308 [amount] => 5.00 [processor] => PayPal [email] => ccarson030308@gmail.com [submitted_date] => 1372030166 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [username] => tatsu91 [amount] => 5.00 [processor] => PayPal [email] => sheynever@yahoo.com [submitted_date] => 1372030166 ) )
```

which should be the only thing it shows to begin with, do I have something wrong in my `for` loop? I don't normally loop `for` and `foreach` but it seemed to be the best method for what I am trying to do, but I am failing somehow.

Without adding the append `[]` I get 12 errors of 
`Warning: Illegal string offset 'amount'
Warning: Illegal string offset 'email'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appends to `$info` for every query made. So when doing `foreach($info ...)` you will see output for the results produced in this iteration *and for all the previous results*.

The output will therefore look like this:

```
-------------- $i = 0
Output from #1
-------------- $i = 1
Output from #1
Output from #2
-------------- $i = 2
Output from #1
Output from #2
Output from #3
-------------- etc
```

You probably meant to write

```
$info = $result->fetch_assoc(); // direct assignment, no append
```

Comment: If i do not add the append I get numerous errors that is why I added the append to begin with
`Warning: Illegal string offset 'amount'`
`Warning: Illegal string offset 'email'`
it repeats those errors 12 times for just the 2 rows

Comment: @kira423: And if you add it you also get errors. So don't make random changes to the code that doesn't work and debug it properly instead. Illegal string offset means that `$row` is not an array. Find out why.

Comment: I am debugging it wasn't a random change, I was just trying a new method before asking the question to ensure that I truly needed the help.